# Points not increasing on right away click but on subsequent click it increases

Tags: java, awt, graphics2d

i have created a color guessing game where the square gets a random color (red or blue) from and array of 2 colors and there are 2 buttons one red and one blue. the game begins with either of the color already in the square and if we guess that the next color will be red we press the red button and if that guess is correct we get 1 point. but somehow that updating of point is not showing right away even when the guess is right and the updating appears only on second clicking of the same red button. in short update is delayed or waiting for next click.

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

class apple1 extends Frame{
    private Button b;
    private Button b2;
    Graphics2D g2;
    TextField tf;
    TextArea lbl;
    int count = 1;
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Color[] clrs = {Color.red,Color.blue};
        Random rand = new Random();
        g2.setColor(clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)]);
        g2.fillRect (60, 50, 200, 200);  
      }
    public apple1(){      
        tf = new TextField("Points: ");
        tf.setBounds(10, 30, 280, 20);

        //create components   
        b=new Button("RED");
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBounds(80,260,80,30); 

        //register listener
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(b.getBackground().equals(g2.getColor())){
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(count++));

         }
                else{
                    tf.setText("Sorry your guess was wrong");       
                }
                repaint();
            }

        });//passing current instance 

        b2=new Button("BLUE");
        b2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        b2.setBounds(180,260,80,30); 

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(b2.getBackground().equals(g2.getColor())){
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(count++));

         }
                else{
                    tf.setText("Sorry your guess was wrong");       
                }
                repaint();
            }

        });//passing current instance         
        //add components and set size, layout and visibility  
        add(b);add(b2);add(tf);  
        setSize(600,600);  
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        }


public static void main(String args[]){  
new apple1();  
}  
}
```

Please help I am feeling so down that I am not able to solve such a small problem.

===========================================================================

As per suggestions by @VGR made modifications to above code. Here is how it looks now and the problem is solved. Thanks @VGR

```
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.TextArea;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

class apple1 extends Frame{
    private Button b;
    private Button b2;
    Graphics2D g2;
    TextField tf;
    TextArea lbl;
    int count = 1;
    private static final Color[] clrs = {Color.red,Color.blue};
    private Random rand = new Random();
    private Color bg = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)];
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(bg);
        g2.fillRect (60, 50, 200, 200);  
      }
    public apple1(){      
        tf = new TextField("Points: ");
        tf.setBounds(10, 30, 280, 20);

        //create components   
        b=new Button("RED");
        b.setBackground(Color.red);
        b.setBounds(80,260,80,30); 

        //register listener
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                bg = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)];
                repaint();
                if(b.getBackground().equals(bg)){
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(count++));

         }
                else{
                    tf.setText("Sorry your guess was wrong");       
                }
            }

        });//passing current instance 

        b2=new Button("BLUE");
        b2.setBackground(Color.blue);
        b2.setBounds(180,260,80,30); 

        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                bg = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)];
                repaint();
                if(b2.getBackground().equals(bg)){
                    tf.setText(String.valueOf(count++));

         }
                else{
                    tf.setText("Sorry your guess was wrong");       
                }
            }

        });//passing current instance         
        //add components and set size, layout and visibility  
        add(b);add(b2);add(tf);  
        setSize(600,600);  
        setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);
        }


public static void main(String args[]){  
new apple1();  
}  
}
```

Comment: Why do you start with count = 1? Use one ActionListener as they are both the same. You know, that you do not check for a future background, but for the current background?

Comment: okay so how do i go about checking the future background. any hint or idea?

Comment: Posted my idea as answer. Btw, use a label to show the word "Points" and use another label to show that the guess was wrong. (Clear it, after each click)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A Graphics (or Graphics2D) object passed to a paint method is only valid for the duration of that paint method.  You cannot use it once the paint method has exited.
2. Paint methods are called by the system.  You don’t have control over how often they’re called.  Paint methods can be called for many reasons in addition to `repaint()` calls, including the window being moved/raised/lowered/resized, and even simply moving the mouse pointer over the window.  For this reason, any logic which alters state must not take place in a paint method.

Move your changing of the background to your ActionListener, and do not attempt to store a Graphics object in an instance field.  Store the Color value itself in a field instead:

```
private static final Color[] clrs = {Color.red,Color.blue};

private final Random rand = new Random();

private Color background = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)];

// ...

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(background);
    g2.fillRect(60, 50, 200, 200);  
}

// ...

    b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (b.getBackground().equals(background)) {
                tf.setText(String.valueOf(count++));
            } else {
                tf.setText("Sorry your guess was wrong");       
            }

            background = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)];
            repaint();
        }
    });

    // Do the same for the other ActionListener...
```

Notice how the paint method does not change anything;  it merely makes use of state variables changed by other methods.  Notice also that no code refers to the Graphics object outside of the paint method.

Comment: tried what you suggested but sorry to say problem not solved.

Comment: [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43939260/edit) and *add* your current code to it.  **Do not** replace the original code that’s currently in your question—that will make it confusing and useless to future readers.  Append your current code to the end of your question’s text.

Comment: made modifications and posted the new code. please check above

Comment: You did not try what I suggested.  Do not refer to `g2` in **any** code outside the `paint` method.  Remove the `Graphics2D g2;` declaration from your class.

Comment: hey...sorry tried it once more without referencing to g2 and instead using bg in equals method but no improvement..made the change to the code above

Comment: yeah it does run but the points increase only after the right guess has already gone and next guess despite being wrong the point increases keeping the previous correct guess in the programs memory..sorry if i am confusing you...but thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Are you saying `count` should increase regardless of whether the guess was right or wrong?  If that’s the case, why not just increase it outside of the `if` statement?

Comment: no the point should only increase on correct guess...that is already happening but the increase in point is delayed until the next click event occurs so even the correct guess may end up throwing the else message of "Sorry....wrong".

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, you’re incrementing `count` after displaying it.  If you want to display a new value, obviously you need to increment it before you display it.

Comment: hey...finally got it working...sorry my bad...but just had to move                  bg = clrs[rand.nextInt(clrs.length)]; repaint(); before the if else statement and voila itworked like a charm..billion thanks. BTW made changes to the code above..

Answer (score 0):

If a button has been pressed store the pressed color.

Random a new background color.

Check if the stored color is the same as the new color.

Add points and set new bg-color.